# Signing out issue with expo that is linked with firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am facing a issue where I can login/register but I cannot sign out in the app.
This is the error I am getting from my terminal:
[image]

In my HomeScreen.js, below contains the code I did for signout:

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      const { user } = signOut()
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
```

Updated HomeScreen.js

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut()
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
```

As this is my first time doing this, I am trying to replicate what I did for login which is

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log(user);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
        }
     }
```

I am guessing this is wrong so can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: can I see your firebase file?

Comment: I'll add an answer please tell me if it's worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import auth from firebase like this:

```
import {auth} from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth);
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
```